# Saving a Class Object or Collection or general object and then loading it up again

Tags: excel, vba

In my VBA project I have created a custom class with different parameters within the class. One of the parameter has a type of "Collection" and one has a type of clsnode (a custom class object) and they basically stores all the Nodes/Root Nodes of a tree view. Now, once I set all the parameters I would like to save all these settings so that when I reopen the workbook it will read and load them.

I have tried creating a Type object and tried to save it as a bin file but then I encountered this compile error: "Can not Get or Put an object reference variable or a variable of user-defined type containing an object reference"

Below are the code that I write in the module:

```
Type TreeData
   ActiveNode As clsNode
   AppName As String
   Changed As Boolean
   CheckBoxes As Boolean
   EnableLabelEdit As Boolean
   FullWidth As Boolean
   Indentation As Single
   LabelEdit As Long
   LineColor As Long
   MoveCopyNode As clsNode
   NodeHeight As Single
   Nodes As New Collection
   RootButton As Boolean
   RootNodes As New Collection
   ShowExpanders As Boolean  
End Type

Function readRoot() As TreeData
    Dim fileName As String, fileNo As Integer, takeRoot As TreeData
    fileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.bin"
    fileNo = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Binary Lock Read As #fileNo
    Get #fileNo, , takeRoot
    'Recovered the TreeData to testVar
    readRoot = takeRoot
    Close #fileNo
End Function


Sub SaveRoot(ActiveNode As clsNode, AppName As String, Changed As Boolean, CheckBoxes As Boolean, EnableLabelEdit As Boolean, FullWidth As Boolean, Indentation As Single, LabelEdit As Long, LineColor As Long, MoveCopyNode As clsNode, NodeHeight As Single, RootButton As Boolean, ShowExpanders As Boolean, Nodes As Collection, RootNodes As Collection)

    Dim fileName As String, fileNo As Integer, storeRoot As TreeData

    storeRoot.ActiveNode = ActiveNode
    storeRoot.AppName = AppName
    storeRoot.Changed = Changed
    storeRoot.CheckBoxes = CheckBoxes
    storeRoot.EnableLabelEdit = EnableLabelEdit
    storeRoot.FullWidth = FullWidth
    storeRoot.Indentation = Indentation
    storeRoot.LabelEdit = LabelEdit
    storeRoot.LineColor = LineColor
    storeRoot.MoveCopyNode = MoveCopyNode
    storeRoot.NodeHeight = NodeHeight
    Set storeRoot.Nodes = Nodes
    storeRoot.RootButton = RootButton
    Set storeRoot.RootNodes = RootNodes
    storeRoot.ShowExpanders = ShowExpanders

    'Now save all testVar variables to a binary file
    fileName = "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\test.bin"
    fileNo = FreeFile
    Open fileName For Binary Lock Read Write As #fileNo
    Put #fileNo, , storeRoot
    Close #fileNo
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line is the error?

Comment: I'm presuming that all of the above code sits in a class? Also, how/when are you calling **readRoot()**?

Comment: @Zac Sorry should have clarify better. I intend to use the readRoot() when I open the workbook. Currently it does nothing as I have not even gone past the SaveRoot() yet. So the step would be firstly create a tree diagram and store all the nodes as a collection. Then clicking a button to run the SaveRoot() to try to assign the TreeData type to save those objects/collections as an external file. Lastly when all the above are successful, I can then reopen the workbook and it will run the readRoot() and load the file.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The SaveRoot() function will be called within a userform button and this should theoretically trigger the module above and save the values. I tried comment out all the parameters with "Collection" and "clsNode" type in the TreeData then it run fine and stored the value. But once I uncomment them it prompt the error. So I assume it must be something to do with not able to store Collection or Objects in general. Basically it stores integers, boolean, string, single, etc except collection and custom objects for some reason.

Comment: I am basically using this guy's free TreeView tool as a template for the work:
https://jkp-ads.com/articles/treeview.asp

It contains all the things I needed except for storing and retrieving the nodes. I am wondering whats the best way to do it.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct: [To place the value of some or all of the object'sproperties in the file, each property must be individually specified.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/can-t-get-or-put-user-defined-type-containing-object-reference).

Comment: I would suggest that you don't *need* to store anything to disk (requirements may dictate otherwise, but it's not a technical limit, IMO). I've worked on projects before where we cached relatively large (several 100,000's of lines) of XML or JSON data in the CustomXMLParts/Custom in order to retrieve/re-use them later and populate the UI/user forms/etc. For custom objects/etc of course you'll need to implement your own methods to convert those complex objects to a string representation and vice versa.